# Angularjs:Crawling ajax site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs, web-crawler

I have read many articles of how to crawl ajax site.i have read in a document that to make ajax site crawlable we have to provide html snapshot of the page.I am using Ruby On Rails as a server side language.

I want to know how the google server translate below url. is it option1 or option2.

Option1

```
http://example.com/#!/program/Chronicle
http://example.com/?_escape_fragment_=/program/Chronicle
```

option2

```
http://example.com/#!/program/Chronicle
http://example.com?_escape_fragment_=program/Chronicle
```

Also is there any need to provide sitemap for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Option 1, as everything after the `#!` is provided.

This post http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/serious-angular-seo.html is a good read and likely covers any other questions you might have with regards to angular and crawlers.

Comment: is there any need to provide sitemap for the site??